# Moving multiple Row Data into its own Column

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've searched StackOverflow and google for quite some time now and haven't been able to find an answer even remotely close to my desired solution using SQL. I have a CSV file (1 table) and it has data for numerous users. The problem is each user has multiple rows with multiple scores but same UserID. I would like to move those scores into their own column to present one row with all of the user's data. How can I achieve this using SQL?

Example of Current Layout:

```
UserID  FNm      LNm   Measure  Score
 0001   person   one   LNF       26
 0001   person   one   NFS       74
 0001   person   one   CFS       54
 0002   person   two   LNF       35
 0002   person   two   NFS       43
 0002   person   two   CFS       33
```

Desired solution:

```
UserID  FNm     LNm   LNF   NFS   CFS
 0001   person  one    26    74    54
 0002   person  two    35    43    33
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, insert all records as is into some temporary table.
Second, insert combined data into needed table; select part is about:

```
select UserID, FNm, LNm,
    max(case when Measure='LNF' then Score else 0 end) as LNF,
    max(case when Measure='NFS' then Score else 0 end) as NFS,
    max(case when Measure='CFS' then Score else 0 end) as CFS
from temptable
group by UserID, FNm, LNm
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load your excel spreadsheet to SQL Server. 
I suggest using SSIS, here is an article to help you:

[http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205](http://SSIS%20-%20Load%20Excel%20File)

then you can use @Arvo's approach to sum the values

Comment: This seems like overkill to me, since we can BULK INSERT a CSV file quite easily without involving Excel and SSIS.

Comment: sure, it can be done, I just rather SSIS that's why I suggested it